# Some maths journals for tough Olympiad and real analysis problems?

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I wanted to know some maths journals and problems magazines like that in crux mathematicorum, American mathematical society, Romanian maths magazine etc. I want to know even more journals with problems and some modern theories regarding maths ,computer science and physics. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.mathproblems-ks.org/

Comment: https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/

Comment: https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journals

Comment: Some more journals of advanced level , could you provide @Prem.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/journal/11858/volumes-and-issues/54-5

Comment: @Prem the springer one seems not to be free and also I am unable to find any problems of maths . Could you please look for some more journals.

Comment: https://www.worldscientific.com/series/mos

Comment: https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx